# How to get value of a nested serializer field from its parent serializer class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider the followings two serializers:

```
class SerializerA(BaseSerializer):
    field_1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    field_2 = SerializerB()

class SerializerB(BaseSerializer):
    field_3 = serializers.IntegerField()
```

The input JSON for SerializerB will not contain field_3 and it has to obtained from field_1 of SerializerA.

I have tried this

```
class SerializerB(BaseSerializer):
    field_3 = serializers.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        if data is not empty and isinstance(data, dict):
            _data = data.copy()
            _data['field_3'] = self.parent.initial_data.get('field_1')
            super(SerializerB, self).__init__(instance, _data, **kwargs)

        super(SerializerB, self).__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)
```

But it is not working as data is always empty and it never passes the if statement.

Comment: why do you think you need to get data from one serializer to another? isn't it better to pass it from views, if your data is the same, pass this data to different serializers, and return those fields that you want

Comment: we only initialize the parent serializer from the views. The child serializer is initialized automatically. Data may not be the same, it can take modifications.

Comment: why do you even use parent serializer? You can create two serializers separetly, and pass data to them separetly from `views.py`

Comment: What is the value of `empty` ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari empty is a built in class within rest framework when no data is passed

Comment: @oruchkin that would complicate the existing code  as I have multiple nested serializers inside a parent serializer

Answer (score 2):

Nested writable deserialization is not supported out of the box in Django Rest, you need to write your own create/update methods:
[documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations), so I think the framework is not even delegating the `data` to child (nested) serializers on initialization.

Another consideration is that the `parent` attribute of the nested serializer (`SerializerB`) is `None` in `__init__`, it is only getting a value in the `bind` method of the nested serializer. So if you want to use the `self.parent.initial_data.get()` construct, you need to do it in the `bind` method of `SerializerB`